# Website url whitelists

Tags: url, whitelist, phishing, nofollow

I'm building a user content parser and am adding an automatic link parser. I'm adding a dialogue, that confirms that the user wants to go to the particular site being linked to. This is for two reasons. Anti phishing and spam combating. However I want to be able to disable both the dialogue and nofollow additions with commonly used websites so I'm building a whitelist. Are there any common whitelists about or should I start building one from scratch?

Comment: Thinking about it I could start with http://www.alexa.com/topsites

Comment: That said, there is a lot of porn websites in the top 500. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This may be very useful to you

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/